# Remove Polyline from QGIS rubberBand

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsrubberband

I am trying to clean existing items in the rubberband. The codes work fine on QGIS 3.2 but on 3.10 crashes.

```
rbs = [ i for i in canvas.scene().items()
                if issubclass(type(i), qgis._gui.QgsRubberBand) ]
if len(rbs)>0:
                for rb in rbs:
                    if rb in canvas.scene().items():
                        canvas.scene().removeItem(rb)
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with this code?
I have another function drawing on the lines on the canvas and this function should remove those.

To regenerate my issue you can run the following code.

```
 #to draw polyline
canvas=iface.mapCanvas()
r = QgsRubberBand(canvas, False)  # False = not a polygon
points = [QgsPoint(-100, 45), QgsPoint(10, 60), QgsPoint(120, 45)]
r.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points), None)


#the next lines are the part I have problem with
rbs = [ i for i in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items()  if issubclass(type(i), qgis._gui.QgsRubberBand) ]
for rb in rbs:
        if rb in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items():
            iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(rb) # this line causes QGIS to Crash
```

I have tested this code on several PC and QGIS. It works perfect on every PC upto QGIS 3.2 and it causes a crash for every version after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing rubberbands in that way(checking an item and removing if a rubberband) is old style. Because, in earlier versions of QGIS 3 there is no a rubberband created by default. But now, if you run `rbs = [i for i ..... ]` line right after opening QGIS, you will see default-created rubberbands. The script above tries to remove those rubberbands and QGIS crashes.

You should add the rubberbands you created to a list and use that list to remove rubberbands.

```
rbs = [] 
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

r = QgsRubberBand(canvas, False)
points = [QgsPoint(-100, 45), QgsPoint(10, 60), QgsPoint(120, 45)]
r.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points), None)
rbs.append(r)

...
...

for item in rbs:
    canvas.scene().removeItem(item)
```

Comment: is there any method I can distinguish between the default rubberbands and the one I creates. 
my problem is I create rubbebands with several different methods and I only have one method cleaning the mapcanvas.

Comment: I have no idea.